# Making a query to sum up all records of a subgroup excluding a specific instance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I'm struggling to make a query that looks at a series of finance records for an individual and gets the amount owing on one record and also (separately) the amount owing on any previous records

Here is the query (cut down from the actual example, and with declared parameters that in the real world are passed to a networked connection). Also in the fullness of disclosure Finance is a view on a pair of tables related to cost and associated payments (which is how "owing" is exposed) but I don't see how that makes any difference.

```
DECLARE @cid INT = 0, @pid INT = 80375

SELECT f.costid, ISNULL(tl.TotalOwing,0) As OtherOwing,  CAST(ISNULL(f.owing, 0) AS float) AS owing
  FROM Finance f 
    LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT Personid, SUM(owing) As TotalOwing FROM Finance
        WHERE COALESCE(revenuedate, DateCreated) < COALESCE(f.revenuedate, f.dateCreated) AND CostID <> f.costid
        GROUP BY PersonID       
  ) tl ON f.personid = tl.personid      
 
 WHERE f.personID = @pid AND f.CostID = CASE WHEN @cid = 0 THEN (
    SELECT TOP 1 costID FROM CostItem WHERE personid = @pid AND abandoned = 0 ORDER BY COALESCE(RevenueDate,datecreated) DESC
 ) ELSE @cid END
```

The problem I have is that the reference to f in the inner query that I am left joining results in an error message about f.costid or f.revenuedate or f.datecreated not being able to be bound and I don't understand why

I have frequently done the same with different records for instance this little snippet below as an example of a subquery referencing another record

```
SELECT p.personID, p.callcentreid, d.appDate
FROM 
    personDetails p 
    LEFT JOIN Calendar c ON c.calendarid = (
        SELECT TOP 1 calendarid FROM calendar WHERE personID = p.personID AND ISNULL(outcome, 'ATT') = 'ATT'
    )
    LEFT JOIN Calendar d ON d.calendarid = (
        SELECT TOP 1 calendarid FROM calendar WHERE personID = p.personID ORDER BY appDate DESC
    )
WHERE  c.calendarID IS NULL
```

So how can I avoid the error and achieve what I want

I'm trying create a statement for the individual that shows current amount owing, and what if anything is owned from previous transactions.

EDIT Specific Error Message

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The multi-part identifier "f.revenuedate" could not be bound.

Comment: You're welcome to document how you solved your problem, but it belongs in an answer, not the question body thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### nope

You can't do what you want with the way you've written the query, but there is a workaround.

The reason why is due to the way [queries are logically processed](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/logical-query-processing-what-it-and-what-it-means-you). In particular the point at which, `SELECT` portions are projected, etc.

I'm going to use local examples to make things simpler.

You can do this:

```
SELECT
    u.DisplayName,
    c.Score
FROM dbo.Users AS u
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        c.UserId,
        Score = SUM(CONVERT(bigint, c.Score))
    FROM dbo.Comments AS c
    GROUP BY c.UserId
) AS c
  ON c.UserId = u.Id;
```

But you can't do this, unless you add `CreationDate` to the select from `Comments`:

```
SELECT
    u.DisplayName,
    c.Score
FROM dbo.Users AS u
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        c.UserId,
        Score = SUM(CONVERT(bigint, c.Score))
    FROM dbo.Comments AS c
    GROUP BY c.UserId
) AS c
  ON c.UserId = u.Id
WHERE c.CreationDate < u.CreationDate;
```

Likewise, you can't do this:

```
SELECT
    u.DisplayName,
    c.Score
FROM dbo.Users AS u
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        c.UserId,
        Score = SUM(CONVERT(bigint, c.Score))
    FROM dbo.Comments AS c
    WHERE c.CreationDate < u.CreationDate
    GROUP BY c.UserId
) AS c
  ON c.UserId = u.Id;
```

But you *can* do this, because apply is a table expression with slightly different rules:

```
SELECT
    u.DisplayName,
    c.Score
FROM dbo.Users AS u
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT
        c.UserId,
        Score = SUM(CONVERT(bigint, c.Score))
    FROM dbo.Comments AS c
    WHERE c.CreationDate < u.CreationDate
    AND   c.UserId = u.Id
    GROUP BY c.UserId
) AS c;
```

Also, outer references are legal in scalar subqueries like in the example you provided:

```
SELECT
    u.DisplayName,
    c.Score
FROM dbo.Users AS u
LEFT JOIN dbo.Comments AS c
  ON c.UserId =
  (
      SELECT 
          v.PostId
      FROM dbo.Votes AS v
      WHERE v.UserId = u.Id
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I already accepted the answer by @Erik Darling, but wanted to rephrase it in the same terms as my question so it was more obvious.  I had put this as an edit to my question, but was asked to make it an answer, so here it is.

```
DECLARE @cid INT = 0, @pid INT = 80375

SELECT f.costid, ISNULL(tl.TotalOwing,0) As OtherOwing,  CAST(ISNULL(f.owing, 0) AS float) AS owing
  FROM Finance f 
    OUTER APPLY ( 
        SELECT SUM(owing) As TotalOwing FROM Finance
        WHERE COALESCE(revenuedate, DateCreated) < COALESCE(f.revenuedate, f.dateCreated) AND CostID <> f.costid AND PersonID = f.personId
  ) tl  
 
 WHERE f.personID = @pid AND f.CostID = CASE WHEN @cid = 0 THEN (
    SELECT TOP 1 costID FROM CostItem WHERE personid = @pid AND abandoned = 0 ORDER BY COALESCE(RevenueDate,datecreated) DESC
 ) ELSE @cid END
```